# How do I make a background that exactly covers the text in Unity, letter by letter?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know how to make a background color that increases its size with the text object. But I can't create the effect in the picture dynamically. I don't know how to color the exact text. I can only make it like the second picture with content size fitter. Any ideas?
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGdmG.png)
[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qf5C.png)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ny37V/, Is this something do you want?

Comment: It seems so. But How I do implement this to Unity?

Comment: Unity? sorry but didn't understand your question?

Answer (score 2):

What's up, You can control the transparency of the highlight by using alpha such as `<mark=#FFFF0080>` or you can actually get the text to be rendered over the highlight by using the font tag which results in the text being part of a sub text object which renders over the highlight.

For instance, let's assume your text object has the BANGERS SDF font asset assigned to it. Using the following `<font="NotoSans SDF">` This `<mark=#FF8000>text is highlighted</mark>`.

[image]

Basically, assign a font asset you are not planning on using in this text and immediately switch to the font asset you are planning to use using the `<font>` tag.

[image]

Just like Underline and Strikethrough which can span multiple lines, the  tag is no different where all of this is handled automatically behind the scene.

This is the raw text in the Text Input Box:

```
<font="NotoSans SDF">This <mark=#FF8000>text is <b>high\u00adlighted</b> <sprite="Sprite Icons" index=7></mark>.
```

The NotoSans SDF is just a font asset that I created from the NotoSans.otf font using the Font Asset Creator in TextMesh Pro.

This `<font="Font Asset Name">` is the font tag itself that allows to use multiple fonts per text object.

[See the font tag information here.](http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/rich-text/#font)

Credit: Big thanks to [Stephan_B](https://forum.unity.com/members/stephan_b.1309638/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will try when I get back to the project and share the results :)