# How to make a text background for TMP in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76491468/how-do-i-make-a-background-that-exactly-covers-the-text-in-unity-letter-by-lett), but it doesn't work for me.

I use `Text Mesh Pro` and want to place background below the text.

I've tried this template, but Unity does not accept the `<font>` tag and displays it as text.

```
<font="MasonChronicles SDF"><mark=#000000FF><color=red>My text</color></mark></font>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your tag. The only issue you have is the wrong path of your font.

According to `Stephan_B`'s answer on [`this question`](https://forum.unity.com/threads/font-tag.779927/), in order your `font asset` to be loaded by `<font>` tag, the `font asset` must be located in the specific folder, which location can be found and edited in `TextMesh Pro Settings`.

`Edit -> Project Settings -> TextMesh Pro -> Settings -> Default Font Asset -> Path`

[image]

So if you want your `MasonChronicles SDF` font to work with `<font>` tag, you should drag its `font asset` into `default font asset's path`, which is `Resources/Fonts & Materials/` by default. The path can also be changed, but still has to be located inside of the `Resources` folder.

[image]

Comment: I have moved the font to the folder you specified. And now the font tag is detected correctly.
But the background is still higher than the text.

https://i.imgur.com/J96v0Xt.jpeg

Comment: This works perfectly for me. The issue may be in your font. Have you tried to implement it with another one?